# Apache Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to build a reverse proxy to front end some virtual desktops that are running VMware View direct connect. I want users to be able to type https://server/desktop1, or https://server/desktop2, based on the path then it needs to reverse proxy to the right IP address.  I have tried numerous rules, with really no luck.

Currently the server is running apache 2.4 and Ubuntu Server 14.

Comment: So where is the question ? Show the configuration you tried: use the edit button and copy the configuration as code into your question

Comment: Which reverse proxy utility are you using?

Answer (score 0):

inside your VirtualHost you should write the followings:

```
ProxyPass /desktop1 http://ip.of.desktop.1/
ProxyPassReverse /desktop1 http://ip.of.desktop.1/

ProxyPass /desktop2 http://ip.of.desktop.2/
ProxyPassReverse /desktop2 http://ip.of.desktop.2/
```

You have also to make sure that you installed and enabled needed modules

```
aptitude install -y libapache2-mod-proxy-html
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod rewrite
a2enmod deflate
a2enmod headers
a2enmod proxy_connect
a2enmod proxy_html
```

then restart apache2 and check...